# Proof of optimal efficiency of A* Search

Tags: search, artificial-intelligence, proof

It is mentioned in Norvig's Artificial Intelligence that A* Search is optimally efficient. However, I could not figure out why nor find on the web the proof. Does anyone happen to have a proof?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm not doing your homework ;). I only sketch the proof here

First thing you need to see is that A* is **optimal**. That is it returns the shortest path according to your cost function `g`. I think this prove is trivial under the assumption that the heuristic `h` is not overestimating the cost of the solution. If this wouldn't hold optimal efficiency would be meaningless, as `A*` wouldn't be optimal.

**Optimal efficiency**: among all **optimal** algorithms starting from the same name node A* is expending the fewest nodes.

Lets assume an algorithm `B` does not expand a node `n` which is `A*` expanded by `A*`. By definition for this path `g(n)+h(n) <= f` where `f` is the cost of the shortest path. Consider a second problem for which all heuristics values are the same as in the original problem. However, there is a new path to a new goal with total cost smaller `f`. 
The assumed algorithm `B` would expand `n` hence never reach this new goal. Hence, `B` wouldn't find this optimal path. Therefore, our original assumption that `B` is optimal is violated.